# How to select records containing a specific value for the max effective term for a group (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following values:

```
Subject Course  Term    Campus
ACCT    2301    201910  WOW
ACCT    2301    201980  WOW
ACCT    2301    201980  63M
ASTR    276T    201910  WOW
ASTR    276T    201980  63M
ENGL    1010    201780  63M
ENGL    1010    201780  VA5
ENGL    1010    201980  63M
ENGL    1010    202080  WSW
ENGL    1010    202080  WOW
```

I want to select only those subject, courses, and terms where
the campus = 'WOW' and the term record is the max term record for
the subject and course.

I've tried multiple selects but I keep seeing the ASTR course in the results.

```
SELECT subject, course, max(term)
FROM test
WHERE 
   subject||course in 
    (SELECT b.subject||b.course FROM test b WHERE b.campus = 'WOW')   
group by subject, course 
;
```

I've also tried:

```
with t0 as
(
  select subject, course, term, campus,
  row_number() over(partition by subject, course, campus order by term) as rn
  from test
)
select subject, course, term
from t0
where rn = 1
and campus = 'WOW';
```

Here are the results:

```
Subject Course  Term
ACCT    2301    201980
ASTR    276T    201910
ENGL    1010    202080
```

I need the results to look like the following:

```
Subject Course  Term    Campus
ACCT    2301    201980  
ENGL    1010    202080
```

(So, ASTR 276T would not be selected because its max term (201980) does not have a campus = 'WOW').

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: but in you sample also  ASTR    276T    201910  WOW   contain WOW so why this value should not be in your expected  result  ??

Comment: He doesn't want it in his result because it's not the max term

Comment: Because the max term for ASTR 276T is 201980 (and there is no "WOW" campus for that term).

Comment: I'm creating this table in a database now so I can try to figure it out

Comment: I have thought about it so much, I think I am brain dead! I bet I'm missing something obvious! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query, plain and beautiful with a single analytic function:

```
with xyz as (
    select X.*,
        dense_rank() over (partition by X.subject, X.course order by X.term desc) as terms_in_group_ordered_desc
    from test X
)
select subject, course, term
from xyz
where terms_in_group_ordered_desc = 1
    and campus = 'WOW'
;
```

Feel free to accept answer and upvote. :-)

Comment: Thank you, nop77svk. This did select the correct values that I needed, but I may need to follow up with you.

Comment: nop77svk, May I add on to the problem? How would I select (for the subject, course, and effective date) all of the campuses EXCEPT the parameter_campus (which is 'WOW' in my example)? So my goal would be to have for ACCT 2301 201980 Campus 63M and for ENGL 1010 202080 Campus WSW (or any other campus assigned to that subject/course/term)?

Comment: @wandasoozq, that would be a different question, so please post another one, you can even put a link to this original question into the new one. (You even will get yourself additional useful skills in asking well-formed stackoverflow.com questions.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select subject,
       course,
       max(term) keep (dense_rank first order by term desc) max_term
  from t
 group by subject, course
 having max(campus) keep (dense_rank first order by term desc, decode(campus, 'WOW', 1, 2) asc) = 'WOW';
```

Sample execution:

```
FSITJA@db01> with t (Subject, Course, Term, Campus) as (
  2  select 'ACCT', 2301, 201910, 'WOW' from dual union all
  3  select 'ACCT', 2301, 201980, 'WOW' from dual union all
  4  select 'ACCT', 2301, 201980, '63M' from dual union all
  5  select 'ASTR', 276T, 201910, 'WOW' from dual union all
  6  select 'ASTR', 276T, 201980, '63M' from dual union all
  7  select 'ENGL', 1010, 201780, '63M' from dual union all
  8  select 'ENGL', 1010, 201780, 'VA5' from dual union all
  9  select 'ENGL', 1010, 201980, '63M' from dual union all
 10  select 'ENGL', 1010, 202080, 'WSW' from dual union all
 11  select 'ENGL', 1010, 202080, 'WOW' from dual)
 12  select subject,
 13         course,
 14         max(term) keep (dense_rank first order by term desc) max_term
 15    from t
 16   group by subject, course
 17   having max(campus) keep (dense_rank first order by term desc, decode(campus, 'WOW', 1, 2) asc) = 'WOW';

SUBJ     COURSE   MAX_TERM
---- ---------- ----------
ACCT       2301     201980
ENGL       1010     202080
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I got your answer that you want but it doesn't like the grouping if I do it like this. Hopefully this gets you in the right direction.

```
SELECT t.Subject, t.Course, t.Term, t.Campus
FROM test t
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Subject, MAX(Term) AS MaxTerm
                    FROM test
                    GROUP BY Subject) q
        ON t.Subject = q.Subject
            AND t.Term = q.MaxTerm
WHERE Campus = 'WOW';
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you want me to explain any of this. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Kyle! I will play with what you have entered here. I'm actually needing to get the campuses other than the "WOW" for the subject/course/term (because we actually want all of the other ones EXCEPT that one), but, hopefully, it is a start.

Comment: Glad I could help, I just started getting into SQL at my internship this summer and I if it helps you at all, that's a win for me :)